# Calculate the limit of $a_{n+1}=\cos\pi a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, problem-solving, nested-radicals

This is my first time to ask a question here, so I'm sorry if I make any mistake.

I'm trying to calculate the limit of $a_n$, which is defined as $a_{n+1}:=\cos\pi a_n$.

The first term is not given in this problem, so I have to prove it by cases.
I am badly stuck not knowing how to find the limit of this sequence and where to start the proof. After I substituted some values of $a1$ and calculate it, I found the convergence value might be $-1$ with almost every $a1$ (there were different ones), but I end up stuck here.

Comment: Assuming the limit exists (it does) there are three possible solutions, one of which being $-1$, the other two being transcendental with likely no closed form

Comment: The other two fixed points (i.e., the ones that aren't $-1$) are repulsive.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt You have forgotten that the sequence can enter a cycle, and have no limit.

Comment: @Nilknarf Not if I assume the limit exists :P

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\cos(\pi x)$. Then, if given $a_0$, you have that
$$a_n=f^n(a_0)$$
In order to find a limit of an iterated function in the form
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f^n(x)$$
the first thing that you need to do is find a fixed point, and then determine whether the fixed point is an attractor or a repeller. To find the fixed point, you must solve the equation
$$\cos(\pi \theta)=\theta$$
Which, unfortunately, has three solutions, one of which is elementary, and the other two of which are transcendental. The elementary solution is 
$$\theta=-1$$
and the transcendental ones are about
$$\theta\approx-0.79,0.38$$
And so the limit can take on any of these three values, depending on the value of $a_0$.

However, sometimes, the sequence has no limit. The sequence can enter a cycle depending on $a_0$, because there exist $a,b$ such that $a \ne b$ and
$$\cos \pi a=b$$
and
$$\cos \pi b=a$$

In general, though, most initial values $a_0$ will result in a limit of $-1$, since $x=-1$ is the only attracting fixed point of the three, and, in fact, is a *superattracting* fixed point, since $f'(-1)=0$. The other two fixed points have
$$|f'(x)|\ge 1$$
and are thus repelling fixed points.

Comment: What does it mean for a fixed point to be attracting or repelling? Can you explain how one can tell which kind a fixed point is?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut In general, at a fixed point  $x=a$ of a function $f$ such that $f(a)=a$, $x=a$ is an attracting fixed point if $$|f'(a)|\lt 1$$, a repelling fixed point if $$|f'(a)|\gt 1$$, and a neutral fixed point if $$|f'(a)|=1$$.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Does that help?

Comment: Because this sequence doesn't enter a circle, the fixed points must be the convergence value, and because the two fixed points other than $-1$ are a repelling fixed point, the convergence value will not be $-1$ only when $a_1$ is on the points. ???

Comment: @Frenchtoast ...I believe that is correct. However, I'm not sure how exactly to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: All limit points (if a limit exists) satisfy

$$\cos(\pi x) = x$$

(that is, if we started with a point that is a limit point, the sequence would be constant).

Edit: Numerically, it seems that the sequence converges to $-1$ for almost all values of $a_1$ (the two other fixed points of $\cos(\pi x)$ are some examples of $a_1$ for which it doesn't converge to $-1$).

Comment: If a_1=1, the sequence is also stationary.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima If $a_1=1$, then $a_n=-1$ for all $n>1$.

Comment: $ \cos( \pi x)=x$ has two solutions and actually almost every $a_1$ converges one, -1 whereas somehow some $a_1$ converges the other.

Comment: @Frenchtoast I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying.

Comment: I read your edit. That's true! Thank you ^_^